# Detect when an event is added to an element

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

How do I detect when an event handler is added to an element?

I came across an article where someone was using a lot of plugins and one of them started snooping around by adding event handlers such as `onkeypress`. I would like to be able to either watch for events being added to a specific element or detect events being added when they are added to a specific element. I am not interested in changes to the DOM itself, only specifically the action of an event handler being added to a specific element. I am also not talking about the HTML attribute version of event handlers (e.g. `<input type="search" onkeypress="" />`) though events added via `addEventListener`. No frameworks or libraries. There is no specific project involved with this (or associated code) other than an HTML element such as a `search` `input` element as an example that someone might want to spy on what someone is searching for. If there are permissions (e.g. stuff being set via an `iframe` or `script` element) that should be taken in to account please.

Comment: Its a good question as I use multiple handlers and emmiters on elements but never been able to see how many event handlers there are on an element

Comment: @JonoJames Thank you. You mean via JavaScript itself? Because it's certainly easily accomplished via Developer tools though I can't be sitting at everyone's computer asking to check their DOM. lol

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to monkeypatch `Element.prototype.addEventListener` (the property is actually on `EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener`). When your custom function runs, you'll know that some other JS has added an event listener, and you can `debugger`, or `console.trace()`, or throw an error to figure out where:

```
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(...args) {
  const eventType = args[0];
  if (eventType === 'keypress') {
    console.log('Keypress listener was just added!');
    console.trace();
  }
  return EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener.apply(this, args);
};
```

```js
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(...args) {
  const eventType = args[0];
  if (eventType === 'keypress') {
    console.log('Keypress listener was just added!');
    console.trace();
  }
  return EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener.apply(this, args);
};

// Somewhere else, an event listener gets added:
button.onclick = () => {
  input.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
    console.log('keypress event just fired');
  });
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Add a listener</button>
<input id="input">
```

Note that mutating the built-in prototypes is almost never a good idea - even if you think you've done it right, it can break things, especially when a script uses libraries. While this technique could be used for debugging, it shouldn't be present in production code.

If you just want to see *what* is attached, and don't actually care about *when*, you can Inspect an element and see which event listeners it currently has:

[image]

Comment: I'm going to try that! I must add I will poll to counter someone who would try to poll (in an attempt to counter my counter) and simply lock down and notify the user that something is wrong. It's late and I may not be able to have a proper response until tomorrow though this is really fascinating. Thank you for posting, I'll reply when I can respond after conducting some meaningful experimentation. :-)

Comment: @John If someone can add run code that adds event listeners to objects on your page, they almost certainly can also overwrite `addEventListener` to keep you from watching what they're adding.

Comment: @jirassimok In my own code I have HTML attributes (which, yes I know is frowned upon though I can *manage them*) so rarely do I use *addEventListener*. Hence why I mentioned `iframe` and `script` elements. I am not aware at how liberal the browsers allow events to be set and I'm sure that is another question to be asked. I appreciate your insight.